# How to reassign touchpad buttons to keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, touchpad, configuration, customization

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on a Lenovo B590 laptop and my touchpad keys seem to be starting to break in the sense that they are always getting stuck and becoming a nightmare to use.

As a workaround until I have managed to fix this annoying hardware issue, I was wondering if there is a way to reassign my touchpad's left- and right-click to keys on my keyboard? I don't mind if this is done through a script or something of the like

Comment: @cl-netbox Oh, sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with Custom Keyboard shortcuts and `xdotool`. Install the tool using:

```
sudo apt install xdotool
```

Then go to *System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Custom*:

[image: keyboard click.png]

- Click on <kbd>+ to create a new shortcut.</kbd>
- Set Name to `Left Click`
- Set Command to `xdotool click 1`
- Click <kbd>Apply</kbd> button
- Click on `Accelerator` option and when prompted for key press `F1`

Repeat process for `Right Click` but assign command as `xdotool click 3` and set the accelerator as `F2`.

Now you can press <kbd>F1</kbd> for left click and F2 for right click.